# How much experience will the Australia Computer Society deduct?

Tags: visa, working-visas, australia

I have done Diploma in computer engineering (3 Years), passed in 2010

I have 7 years of experience as a software engineer experience

How much experience will deduct by ACS (Australian Computer Society)?

Comment: Close voters (@mts ?), PLEASE left a comment with your reason for your close vote. "Unclear" is not enough a reason - you need to indicate what is unclear.

Comment: @markmayo I did not vote on this question. However I think the question requires more context.

Comment: @mts all good, not sure who did but given your edit I thought I'd take a guess.

Comment: Jalay just don't go to Australia... they are racist... especially against Indian and Vietnamese like hell... I would suggest to migrate to UK instead...

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius - how to migrate to UK? assume not to go for studdy but as a skilled migrant in IT technology sector

Comment: UK is much harder to get PR then other nations.

Answer (score 3):

Going from the [current guidance](https://www.acs.org.au/content/dam/acs/acs-skills/Skills%20Assessment%20Guidelines%20for%20Applicants%20-%20August%202017.pdf) it would be 5 or 6 years

From the ACS guidelines (highlights are mine)

> Diploma and Vendor Certification
>
> If your Diploma or Vendor
> Certification is assessed as having an **ICT major which is closely
> related to your nominated occupation**, you will require **5 years**
> relevant work experience completed within the past 10 years or 6 years
> relevant work experience completed anytime in your past work history
> (whichever provides the earliest skill date) to meet the suitability
> criteria.
>
> If your Diploma or Vendor Certification is assessed as
> having an **ICT major which is NOT closely related to your nominated
> occupation**, you will require 6 **years relevant work experience**
> completed anytime in your past work history to meet the suitability
> criteria.

If it turns out that your diploma is classified as having insufficient ICT content then you will have to do a Recognition of Prior Learning as well.

So you would likely be left with 1 or 2 years experience depending.

Good luck with your application.

Comment: Thanks @Crab Bucket well I will go for 261313 ANZSCO code as My designation is software engineer with 7 years of experience and 10 + 3 years of a diploma in Computer Engineering. Is it come in ICT Major?